# MVVM Light Messenger Cleanup logic does not work if Register or Unregister is called within Task.Run

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, mvvm-light

Debugging a memory leak, I noticed that Messenger was holding onto a few disposed objects. Investigating further, I found that if `Register` is called from within Task.Run, `Messenger.Cleanup` will never run afterward via `RequestCleanup`.

When registering and unregistring, `RequestCleanup` is called which adds a call to Cleanup to the current thread's Dispatcher and sets `_isCleanupRegistered` to `true`. The problem is, the Dispatcher created here via `Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher` never runs `Cleanup` and `_isCleanupRegistered` is never set back to `false`. Subsequent calls to `RequestCleanup` never get passed the check for `_isCleanupRequested`.

```
public void RequestCleanup()
{
        if (!_isCleanupRegistered)
        {
            Action cleanupAction = Cleanup;

            //...other code

            Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.BeginInvoke(
                cleanupAction,
                DispatcherPriority.ApplicationIdle,
                null);

            _isCleanupRegistered = true;
        }
    }
```

If I change `Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher` to `Application.Current.Dispatcher`, `Cleanup` runs as expected. What is the correct way to register and unregister such that the cleanup logic works as expected?

Note that this is the **WPF 4.5** version of MVVM Light.